# Angular Material Menu is not eagerly loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a problem with Angular Material Menu v6.3.2
Here is a [link to docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#lazy-rendering)  where it says:

> By default, the menu content will be initialized even when the panel
>   is closed.

But even on the same page, the very first example doesn't behave that way. Menu items are loaded only when the `Menu` button is clicked

[image]

That `div.cdk-overlay-container` section is created on `Menu` button click.

Is there a way to make it really load menu items with page load?

Comment: You have to open menu when page is loaded? is something like that?

Comment: I don't want to visually open the menu. But I want to make all HTML loaded with page load, to make it more SEO friendly

Comment: Let me put your query in this way: You want to load all HTML content when page loads including menu items?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You should read the documentation about `menu` completely. It says, `To defer initialization until the menu is open, the content can be provided as an ng-template with the matMenuContent attribute:`. You could play with `directives` to achieve what you want....